# WatchKit app submission failure; MinimumOSVersion

Tags: ios, watchkit

Submitting WatchKit 1.2 companion app, fails during validation with this error:

ERROR ITMS-90455 "Invalid WatchKit App Bundle. The value '2.1' for the MinimumOSVersion key in info.plist in bundle 'redactedbundlename.watchkitapp' is not supported"

I do cannot find a MinimumOSVersion key in the watch app plist or settings, nor in build settings or plist for the phone app.

The only mention of anything "2.1" related is in my build settings:

[image]

Any ideas to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this?

Comment: Same issue for me. Just updated an old app and removed watchOS 1, added watchOS 2, and now stuck with this error during submission.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Fixed it!**

For some reason, you need to change **WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET** from **2.1** to **2.0**.

[image]

You can find this in Project Settings -> "Watch App Target" -> Build Settings ->  (null) - Deployment -> **watchOS Deployment Target** 
(or just search 2.1 in entire project and it should show up in the results)

I am guessing this is a bug, maybe watchOS 2.1 is still marked as 'beta' in Xcode/iTunes Connect, so that when you try to upload to iTunes Connect it rejects it due to bad version.

Comment: I did the same and i was able to upload to itunes connect but when I go to external testing and Add a Build, it lists the build as "This build is invalid" did you get this error?

Comment: There is no option for watchOS 2.0 in the list for me (I'm using Xcode 7.2), so I'm stuck building for 2.1, but I can't upload to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Ah, it's the "watchOS Deployment Target" you should look for, not the "Base SDK" setting.

Comment: What is the difference between Base SDK and Deployment Target? Or better, I know what the second one is; what is the first?

Answer (score -1):

This might not do it, but I would try looking at the project settings (OS version) for both the WatchKit extension and WatchKit app to ensure that they are what you want. Click on your project container, then at the top left of the menu with things like "General", "Capabilities", etc. Select all the options on that dropdown list and check the OS version.

Comment: This is very good general advice, and I have done so, but everything "looks good" and so I would not know what to alter.  App is SDK 8.2, watch is SDK 2.1.

Comment: What does "Capabilities" have to do with the original issue?